# cant get table and text to sit next to each other properly

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to get this 'table' (don't know what else to call it) and text to sit next to each other properly. As I add more text the table moves down. I want it to stay in the same place ideally so it's aligned with the text properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
div.content2 {
  margin-right: 51%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: static;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 532px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    p {
      margin-left: 50em;
      margin-right:
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <H4 style="margin-left:3em; "> News </H4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut lacinia vestibulum quam sit amet aliquet. dsfsnffskdnfsdznf kdhnsfksdnfksdfnk hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
  </p>

  {% paginate blogs.Studio.articles by 100 %} {% for article in blogs.Studio.articles limit: 5 %}
  <div class="content2">
    <h4><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>
    {{ article.excerpt | strip_html | truncatewords:70 }}
  </div>
  {% endfor %} {% endpaginate %}
</body>
```

Comment: Should this be wrapped in a container or something?

Comment: What do you mean by table? Because no any`<table>` in your code.

Comment: Its actually the Paginate Blogs part down. It doesn't render on here because it's linked to a currently not live shopify site. I need that and the text above it to sit next to each other